# I am using image-size module of Nodejs in my code .Can anyone tell me what unit it measures the dimensions of the image( its not pixels I checked )

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, image-size

Below is a simple code that requires "image-size" module Nodejs, in the variable "sizeOf" and calls it along with the parameter as the image name in its current directory. Then it prints that image's width and height. I need to know in what unit it measures the image.

```
const sizeOf = require('image-size');

(async () => {

dimensions = sizeOf("photo.jpg") 
    console.log("width: ", dimensions.width,"height: ", dimensions.height)


})();
```

Output= width:  192 height:  612
Dimension in a file folder for photo.jpg= width: 750 pixels height: 750 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit is actually in pixels because an image is also measured in pixels.